# Rails acts_as_taggable titelize tag list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, title, acts-as-taggable-on

I have this code that outputs a list of users' interests and I can't figure out how to titleize each tag of the list.

```
<%= raw follower.pursuit_list.map { |p| link_to p, "#" }.join(', ') %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
follower.pursuit_list.map { |p| link_to p.name.titleize, "#" }.join(', ').html_safe
```

It implies that the PursuitList object responds to the `name` method, which I consider as the Tag's name in this code.